# PHPMailer and Smarty - send email to inputter

Tags: php, email, smarty, phpmailer

I have two PHP files. One contains a string of email addresses to which an email is sent from a form (well it uses Lables not a form tag) on a site (this is basicly to a load address of admin users).
In the second PHP is the config for the PHP mailer.
One of the fields in the Form/class asks for the Users email address. 
I'm wanting to BCC the email which is sent to the admin users to the person who inputted the form.

As the data in the email also contains the email address I wanted to extract this in PHP into a Varable. However I have tried this but due to the system using Smarty I cant get it working! Any ideas?

```
public function SendEmail( $email_address_array, $email_data, $subject, $template, &$send_message ) {

    $smartyObj = Configurator::getInstance()->smarty;   
    $send_message = '';
    $send_result = 0;



    try { 

        $mail = new PHPMailer( true );      
        $mail->IsSMTP( true );  // telling the class to use SMTP
        $mail->SMTPDebug = false;
        $mail->IsHTML( true );
        $mail->Host = Configurator::getInstance()->getSettings( "phpmailer_smtp" ); 

        $mail->ClearAddresses();
        for( $x = 0;$x < sizeof($email_address_array);$x++ ){
            $mail->AddAddress( trim($email_address_array[$x]));
        }       


        $smartyObj->assign( 'email_data', $email_data );
        $mail->SetFrom( 'info@forexchange.co.uk', 'Forexchange Currency Order');

    // THIS IS WHAT I TRIED BUT NOT WORKING!    
    //  Search Email from $email_data Script
    //  $pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i'; 
    //  $smartyObj->assign( 'pattern', $pattern );
    //  preg_match_all($pattern, $email_data, $matches);
    //  $smartyObj->assign( 'email', $matches[0][0] ); 

        // Send CC Email
    //  $mail->AddAddress( trim($email));


        $mail->Subject  = $subject;
        $mail->Body     = $smartyObj->fetch( $template );           
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
        } else {
            $send_result = 1;
        }
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        $send_message = $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $send_message = $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
    }
    //echo $send_result;
    //exit;
    return $send_result;
}       


/***************************************************************/
/***************************************************************/
```

}

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do here. Why pass the pattern to Smarty? Why add *all* those addresses to PHPMailer? You don't need to `clearAddresses` when you have a fresh instance.

Comment: Basicly I'm trying to split the varable which comtains an email address from the form and then send the same email via BCC to that email address. However because it's using some smarty template I cant seem to extract the email address using the script inside of the //s which you can see above.

Comment: I don't see why you would need to get the addresses *out* of the template - surely you should have an array of addresses that you pass *in* to the template, and use the same ones for PHPMailer? Trying to parse things out of a template seems completely backwards. Also, I hope you're not intending to use target addresses submitted from the form - that's open to abuse.

Comment: Inside of $email_data is an email address which I need to put into a varable so I can send the same email to them via BCC. That email address is not in an array as its inputted by the user into a form. I could normaly extract it from the varable but due to Starty it's not working.

Comment: This is still incomprehensible. If you're passing something to Smarty, you must have that thing beforehand - you don't need to get it back from Smarty. If you have a form element that's submitted by a user, it will be in `$_POST` (or maybe `$_GET`); Smarty isn't involved with processing the page submission. The code you have passing a regex pattern to Smarty makes no sense at all.